# What's the equivalent of calling Activity.finish() in a WinForms application?

Tags: c#, winforms, activity-finish

In Android when finished with an Activity and want to return to previous activity you use `finish();`.

Is there an equivalent in WinForms using C#? In my application once the user clicks the `Enter` button I want the user to return to previous window.

Comment: Which framework are you using? WinForms? WinRT? WPF? Windows Phone?

Comment: maybe return fits your needs

Comment: I tried return; doesn't do anything.

Comment: What is an "activity" in this context?

Comment: A windows form with several checkboxes and an enter key.  When the enter key is pressed I want the program to return to the main class.

Comment: @Aaron You mean you want to close the form? Just call the `Close()` method

Comment: Thanks, exactly the answer I needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base on a superficial understanding of an [Activity in Android (sounds like a window element)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html), you just need to call [`Close`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.close%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on the current window, then the previous one will then move to the foreground.

For future reference however, I would advise you not too create such analogies between two radically different technologies since the life cycle of an Activity in Android is radically different from a form in a Windows Form application. You should try to learn the framework rather than replicating an implementation from a different framework/platform.

Comment: +1 - Better yet, [set the `DialogResult`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16846573/using-dialogresult-correctly)