# C# Application not getting terminate on other machine

Tags: c#

I am using `System.Environment.Exit(0)` in my c# application. While using this, application gets terminated but when i build an .exe file and using this application on another machine, its seem to not trminate application.

```
    btnClose_Click(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
System.Environment.Exit(0)
};
```

Comment: What does it do then? Sure the line is called? Can you show surrounding code?

Comment: private void btnClose_Click(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {System.Environment.Exit(0)};

Comment: It does actually but on my machine but when i am running its .exe on another machine, it does't

Comment: Does machine configuration matters means OS compatibility and all ?

Comment: What happens on the other machine when reaching that line of code?

Comment: Do **not** use Environment.Exit to close your program, it can miss out some steps of your programs shutdown.. what are you using? Winforms?

Comment: Does the process crashes? `Environment.Exit` will crash in some OS. Use `Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill`. Agreed both are brutal way of killing the process.

Comment: @Nuhuel On other machine, application is working fine but when i click on close button, the form not clossing

Comment: @Sayse yes...it is winform

Comment: then just use `this.Close()`

Comment: @Sayse this.close() will close current form only but if child form also running same time then this solution won't work

Comment: Child forms get closed with their parent, so that needs to be done on the main form, there isn't normally a lot of need to close a program other than from the main form

Comment: @Sayse totally agreed with you... but here my scenario is, i am asking a password on close form and for accepting password i am using another form so in this case(this.close()) my form having password,getting close but main form remains open

Comment: You should just return a dialogresult from the password form and then based on this, close your program

Comment: @Sayse can u describe pl

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58742/discussion-between-user1280492-and-sayse).

Comment: There will be plenty of examples around about this [here is just one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16846573/using-dialogresult-correctly)