# How to know if the dialog box is closed completely?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, showdialog

I have a parent form `Form1` which is opened in fullscreen mode. There's a button in `Form1` which opens a form `Form2` (using `.ShowDialog()` method). When the form is closed, the program captures the screenshot of the `Form1`. But in the screenshot I can still see the `Form2` which still has some opacity during closing (I'm using `Microsoft Windows 7 Pro` which animates the closing of the form by reducing the opacity of the form).

So how can I know when the `Form2` is 100% closed, so that I can take screen shot of the program?

**Edit:** I'm using [Graphics.CopyFromScreen Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cdcw1c3b(v=vs.100).aspx) in `Form1` to capture the screen shot.

And `Form2` is closed by the button click in `Form2` using `this.Close()` method.

Comment: What method do you use for closing Form2?

Comment: I think this is because animations in windows theme. how do you capture screen shot of the form1?

Comment: You should add your code that you use to close the form as well as the code that opens/screenshots it (presuming this is with `ShowDialog()`)

Comment: Related question: [Capture screenshot of active window?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163761/capture-screenshot-of-active-window)

Comment: how about waiting 1 second and then capture screenshot?

Comment: So there's no way to know programmatically?

Comment: Maybe using the OnClosed event is what you want to do ?

Comment: @L16H7 - You can possibly use `form.Visible` to see if it is still visible but I'd imagine this is flaky at best. The better option would be to actually screenshot the window rather than the screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there's a way to know for sure the Windows desktop manager animation has completed, it's not in .NET itself. You'd have to find a native API that provides this detail (and I'm not sure one exists…I'm not aware of one if it does) and execute it via p/invoke.

I think commenter/answerer [dotctor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3970411/dotctor) has provided a couple of good options: just delay long enough to account for the animation, or shift the offending window out of the way as it's closing (and if you do reuse the same `Form2` instance, shift it back before displaying it again).

That said, you might also consider using the [`Control.DrawToBitmap()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.drawtobitmap(v=vs.110).aspx) method to do the screenshot, since you seem to want the image to be the full-screen image of the `Form1` window. It has some limitations (which you can read about in the docs), but as long as none of those apply in your case, it might be a more convenient way to get the image you want.

Comment: So how to create a delay of 1 sec.?

Comment: `Thread.Sleep(1000)`, also it is not a good idea to call it on UI thread. @L16H7

Comment: @L16H7: that's a whole separate question! :) You didn't offer enough of a code example to know how in _your_ code you should create the delay. You can use things like `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`, or `Task.Delay()`, for example.

Answer (score 2):

I came up with an easy solution that contains no waiting.

add an handler to `FormClosing` event on `Form2` and set its location to somewhere off screen.

```
private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
   this.Location = new Point(-4000,-4000);
}
```

Comment: This would be very annoying however if you wish to reopen the same dialog

Comment: previous location can be stored and then restored on `Shown` @Sayse

Comment: @Sayse How can you reopen a disposed dialog? You'd have to create a new one in any case.

Comment: closing a form is not disposing it. you can call close, showdialog as long as you have not disposed your form. @Rotem

Comment: @Rotem - Simply by closing it, doesn't necessarily fully dispose of it ([for example, see quote](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16846573/using-dialogresult-correctly))

Comment: `Thread.Sleep(1000)` solved the problem. Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: I've been living a lie!