# c# winforms, I want to pass a primitive variable by Ref from a Form1 to another Form2's construct, and have the ability to alter its value

Tags: c#, winforms

Form1 has the following code :

```
 private void deleteMem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bool delete = false;
            choiceCheck choiceCheck = new choiceCheck(ref delete,"Supprimer le membre", "Êtes-vous sûr de vouloir supprimer le membre (" + CDMDisplay.Text + ") " + FNDisplay.Text + " " + LNDisplay.Text, "Supprimer", "Annuler");
            choiceCheck.ShowDialog();

            if (!delete) return;
...
```

and Form2 has :

```
        public bool accept;
        public choiceCheck(ref bool accept, string title, string message, string yesText, string noText)
        {

            InitializeComponent();
            this.Text = title;
            this.message.Text = message;
            this.yesButton.Text = yesText;
            this.noButton.Text = noText;
            this.accept = accept;
        }
        private void yesButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            accept = true;
            this.Close();
        }

        private void noButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            accept = false;
            this.Close();
        }
```

Form2 is like MessageBoxButtons.YesNo but as a Form.
I want to pass ref of **delete** to Form2 and have it alter its value.

I could make '**bool delete**' a public variable and then alter it from Form2 as a solution, but is there any way to alter variable delete without declaring it public ?

Comment: ShowDialog returns a DialogResult value. This value is obtained from the DialogResult property of the buttons. So, if you just ask for a yes-no answer there is no need to pass a ref variable to the form. Just look at the DialogResult returned by ShowDialog and you will be able to understand which button has been pressed.

Comment: You don't need to use a ref variable here. Just add a public property that returns `accept`. (Or use the existing `DialogResult` property)

Comment: Yes that will work, albeit is a bit confusing having everything on the same line. See here: [Using DialogResult correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16846573/using-dialogresult-correctly)

Answer (score -1):

That is not at all how this pattern is supposed to work. You need to either use `DialogResut` to return a yes/no, or have a property available with the result when the form closes.

### MainForm.cs

For example, here is the main form which calls the confirmation form and depending on the `DialogResult` value it branches one way or another.

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ConfirmForm dlg = new ConfirmForm()
        {
            Title = "Confirm Membership",
            Message = "By accepting this membership you ...",
            YesText = "Confirm",
            NoText = "Cancel",
        };

        if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            // accepted
            label1.Text = "Accepted";
        }
        else
        {
            // canceled
            label1.Text = "Canceled";
        }
    }
}
```

#### ConfirmForm.cs

and here is the confirmation form with the logic to handle setting the text labels and setting the proper value in `DialogResult`

```
public partial class ConfirmForm : Form
{
    public ConfirmForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);

        this.AcceptButton = yesButton;
        this.CancelButton = noButton;

        yesButton.Click += (s, ev) =>
        {
            DialogResult = DialogResult.Yes;
            this.Close();
        };
        noButton.Click += (s, ev) =>
        {
            DialogResult = DialogResult.No;
            this.Close();
        };
    }
    public string Message { 
        get => messageLabel.Text; 
        set => messageLabel.Text = value; }
    public string YesText
    {
        get => yesButton.Text;
        set => yesButton.Text = value;
    }
    public string NoText { 
        get => noButton.Text; 
        set => noButton.Text = value; }
    public string Title { 
        get => Text; 
        set => Text = value; }
}
```