# Backgroundworker's RunWorkerCompleted event is firing even before completing the work

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, backgroundworker

I am using the BackgroundWorker thread to perform a long task(basically reading a big xml file). For the first time the worker works fine as desired, but if I upload a second xml file,  using the same background worker it works fine sometimes but most of the time the Backgroundworker's RunWorkerCompleted is fired even before the DoWork event. Some of the code is displayed below

```
    private void openFile_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
          // Code removed for brevity
  worker = new BackgroundWorker();
            worker.RunWorkerAsync();
            worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork);
            worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            worker.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(worker_ProgressChanged);
            worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(worker_RunWorkerCompleted);
       }

        void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataImport();
        //worker.Dispose();
        //worker.Disposed += new EventHandler(worker_Disposed);
        //worker.DoWork -= worker_DoWork;
        //worker.RunWorkerCompleted -= worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
        //worker = null;
        //GC.Collect(GC.GetGeneration(worker), GCCollectionMode.Forced);
    }
```

worker is a globally defined variable. What is wrong here I am not getting. Kindly help

Comment: A few hints for Completed: Don't call `GC.Collect()`, Do inspect `e.Error`.

Comment: Not possible to answer w/o seeing at least an outline of DoWork().

Comment: If your DoWork function spawns a thread to perform its work, and you don't do a .Join(), DoWork will return instantly.  But as @Henk said, need to see what DoWork does.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should add the `DoWork`-event handler (and all other event handler, too) *before* calling `RunWorkerAsync()`.

Otherwise, it could happen that `RunWorkerAsync` does practically nothing.

Comment: True, but does not really explain the symptoms "is fired even before the DoWork event".

Comment: Might also want to mention, since he's re-using the worker, that he should make sure not to add the event handlers multiple times.

Comment: @JimMischel Also, he's re-using the event handlers, so maybe the `RunWorkerCompleted` event that is fired does not belong to the "current" background worker.

Comment: The OP is creating a new Bgw each time. And the commented-out code really tries to eradicate the old one. Both are sufficient to exclude reuse of handlers.

Comment: @DominicKexel Thanks a lot for the reply. But why is it like this, RunWorkerCompleted Event should execute only after the worker is done with its work irrespective of where we are assigning handler to the event. Any Idea ?

Comment: @Vikram RunWorkerCompleted += ... is _not_ being invoked by you but by the BackgroundWorker.  You're only assigning the work for it to go do when it determines it is the appropriate time to do so. More importantly you need to assign the DoWork+= before RunWorkerAsync() on the same concept - that BGW needs an assigned function when it determines it is time to handle a given event. RunWorkerAsync will start and when it determines resources are available enough, it will begin the assigned "DoWork". When "DoWork" has completed the BGW will know and will then look to see if "Completed" is assigned.

Answer (score 2):

It should be like this:

```
worker = new BackgroundWorker();
worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;

worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork);
worker.ProgressChanged += 
    new ProgressChangedEventHandler(worker_ProgressChanged);
worker.RunWorkerCompleted += 
    new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(worker_RunWorkerCompleted);

worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

`RunWorkerAsync` should be called after subscribing to the `DoWork` and `RunWokerCompleted` events.

Answer (score 2):

you should check first that background worker is busy or not, using this....

> ```
>         backgroundWorker1.DoWork += backgroundWorker1_DoWork;
>         backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted;
> ```

```
        if (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)
        {
            backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

As said in https://stackoverflow.com/a/16809596/8029935, you can be blindly assuming that the worker has finished the job and produced a result when DoWork Method dies from an exception. Which is caught by BackgroundWorker and passed to the RunWorkerCompleted event handler as the e.Error property.

So, I suggest you must check that property using a try/catch statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you Call another async function in your BackgroundWorker _DoWork event,

like;

```
    private void BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        somethingsToDoAsync();
        // somethingsToDoAsync() function is to ASYNC 
    }
```

_RunWorkerCompleted fires even before completed _Dowork event.

Change another function to not async.